# Rotation of Icosahedron sitting on a table.

Tags: geometry

I'm sure there are many answers to this question but what is a valid rotation for a Icosahedron(D20) sitting flat on a table. Let's say the starting rotation is 0,0,0. How could I do the calculations to find one of these valid rotations?

Comment: What calculation do you mean? Like a rotation matrix?

Comment: "Valid" rotation? What does that mean?

Comment: Yea that was a poor choice of works. What I meant was, what is an example of X,Y,Z coordinates for a Icosahedron sitting on a table. What I failed to realize was I didn't provide a reference for how the Icosahedron was originally oriented so this question was unanswerable. I since then found a solution. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

The icosahedron is sitting on one of its faces, which is an equilateral triangle.  The rotations around the vertical axis that map the icosahedron to itself must leave this triangle invariant, so they will be by multiples of $2\pi/3$ radians.

Comment: Cool so that would be equal to 120 degrees right? If the rotation was being expressed in x,y,z format what would be needed?